# Is there any reason for this code not to return true or is just JavaScript quirks

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn how to implement LinkedList by examining each line of code, so I came across one line of code that should return true instead it returns false and the line of code is this.head it should return true is obvious I can't understand please help.

```
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor(){
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }
    static add(value) {
        //let node = new Node(value);
        if(this.head === null){
            // this.head equals to null but returns false don't know why
            console.log(true)
       
        }else {
            console.log(false)
        }
    }
}
LinkedList.add()
```

Comment: There is no instance of `LinkedList`. `this` is the class, which has no data members.

Comment: So static is worthless at this point if I understand what you mean?

Comment: It's not worthless, you're just not using a static method for the purpose it was intended.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you never create an instance of the LinkedList class.
This for example would work:

```js
let list = new LinkedList()
list.add()
```

If you don't create an instance. Then the `constructor (){...}` content never executes

Comment: Only if `add` is non-static.

Comment: If the answer fixed your problem, give it a checkmark!